# Limit log size for OPENVMS FTP Server

Tags: ftp, openvms

is there a way to control log file size on the openvms ftp server?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the service creates a new log file, this one you can control

more information on:

http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=1477805